# Chain rule clarification?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I am not understanding how if you have some function that is f(g(x)) that the derivative of that function is f '(g(x)) g '(x). This doesn't make sense to me because shouldn't f'(g(x)) be f'(g(x))? I know this must be an incredibly stupid question but can someone please help? For instance, sqrt((3x+5)^2). The rule says to differentiate ((3x+5)^2) which is 2(3x+5) and then multiply it by 3, or the derivative of 3x+5, to get 6(3x+5). Now my question is pretty much this, if the first step of differentiating this is to differentiate the entire thing, then aren't we done because the derivative of ((3x+5)^2) is 2(3x+5)?

Comment: King Squirrel, we meet again. Why do you think it should be that?

Comment: You're good at explaining things so help me out please!!!

Comment: $2(3x+5)$ is not just the derivative of $(3x+5)^2$; it is derivative of $(3x+5)^2$ *with respect to* $3x+5$.  Which is not equal to the derivative *with respect to* $x$; being $6(3x+5)\\$  When asked for a derivative it is always *with respect to* some variable parameter; either explicitly or implied by context of the discussion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$2(3x+5)$ is not just the derivative of $(3x+5)^2$; it is derivative of $(3x+5)^2$ *with respect to* $3x+5$.  Which is not equal to the derivative *with respect to* $x$ , that being: $6(3x+5)$

When asked for a derivative it is always *with respect to* some variable parameter; either explicitly or implied by context of the discussion.

Thus when asked to find the derivative of $f(g(x))$ it is implied to be with respect to $x$, the independent variable of the discussion.

---

The following are equivalent expressions

$$\begin{align}
 \frac{\operatorname d f(g(x))}{\operatorname d x}  & =\frac{\operatorname d f(g(x))}{\operatorname d g(x)}\cdot\frac{\operatorname d g(x)}{\operatorname d x} 
\\[2ex]
 [f(g(x))]' & =f'(g(x))\cdot g'(x)
\\[2ex]
 [f\circ g]'(x) & = [f'\circ g \cdot g'](x)
\\ & = [f'\circ g](x)\cdot g'(x)
\end{align}$$

The main point is that $f'(g(x))$ is the derivative of $f(g(x))$ w.r.t. $g(x)$; and **not** the derivative of $f(g(x))$ w.r.t. $x$.

$$f'(g(x)) = \frac{\operatorname d f(g(x))}{\operatorname d g(x)}{\Large \neq} \frac{\operatorname d f(g(x))}{\operatorname d x}$$

Comment: Can you tell me more about what you mean by it is the derivative of that function with respect to 3x+5?

Comment: @KingSquirrel Because the derivative of $u^2$ with respect to $u$ is $2u$ so by substitution therefore the derivative of $(3x+5)^2$ with respect to $3x+5$ is $2(3x+5)$. Via:  $\dfrac{\operatorname d (3x+5)^2}{\operatorname d (3x+5)} = 2(3x+5)$

Comment: I guess I just don't understand how it would work if something is the derivative of something else with respect to a function like 3x+5. I know how it would work for say, a derivative of something with respect to time as opposed to something else.

Comment: This is a solid answer.

Comment: @KingSquirrel Think about what it means to take the derivative. We want to know the *rate of change* of the function, i.e., how much the function changes given a very small change in $x$. When we look at what happens when that change approaches $0$, we say we take the derivative of that function *with respect to* $x$. Now suppose instead, we look at how much the function changes given a very small change in something that *isn't* $x$, like $3x+5$. Now, a change in this causes a differently sized change in the function; this is the derivative *with respect to* $3x+5$.

Comment: @Vedvart1 Basically yes. That differencetly sized change is reflected in the derivative of $3x+5$ *with respect to* $x$. $$\begin{split}\frac{\mathsf d(3x+5)^2}{\mathsf d x}&=\frac{\mathsf d(3x+5)}{\mathsf d x}\cdot\frac{\mathsf d(3x+5)^2}{\mathsf d(3x+5)} \\&= 3\cdot\left[\frac{\mathsf d u^2}{\mathsf d u}\right]_{u\gets 3x+5} \\&= 3\cdot\left[2u\right]_{u\gets 3x+5} \\&= 6(3x+5)\end{split}$$

Answer (score 1):

So we have the function:

$$f(x) =(3x+5)^2$$

Let $g(x) = 3x + 5$, therefore we have that $g'(x) = 3$

We have that:

$$f(x) = (g(x))^2$$

$$f'(x) = 2*(g(x))*g'(x)$$

$$f'(x) = 2(3x+5)*3 = 6(3x+5)$$

Hope this helped.

Answer (score 1):

A helpful way of thinking about differentiating chain functions is to think about them like they're your grandma wrapped in a big winter coat.

In this case your grandma is :
$$g(x)= 3x+5$$

Her big poofy coat is $$f(x) = (grandma)^2$$
(doesn't she look nice and cozy?)

...or in more formal terms $$f(x) = (g(x))^2$$

Keep in mind that *f* isn't *just* your grandma and isn't *just* her coat, it's your *grandma in her coat*.

So when someone asks you to differentiate your grandma in her coat, don't just differentiate her coat (as you would be doing in your last question). Go ahead and differentiate the coat, followed by your grandma. Then you've differentiated the entire function and you're all set.

So,

$$f'(x) = 2(3x+5)*3$$
$$f'(x) = 6(3x+5)$$